# Angular js factory to consume asp.net webApi

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

How do I consume a webApi in an angular js factory?

**WebApi**

```
public class WarrantyController: ApiController {
    public WarrantyViewModel Get(string c, string l, string s, string cs, string productcode, string ordercode, string overrides) {
        var response = Query(new WarrantyQuery(UserContext.CreateContext(c, l, s, cs), productcode, ordercode, overrides));
        return response.Data;
    }
}
```

this returns json result :

GET /api/shop/warranty/get/us/en/abc/19/productA/abc-123 HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 1):

Angular Resource module is a really good helper to consume Rest APIs.

You can create a factory like :

```
angular.module('appService', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Warranty', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/warranty/');
    });
```

Then, inject your factory into your angular application as shown below:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['appService']);
```

Finally, you can access your factory in your controller:

```
app.controller('warrantyController', function($scope, Warranty) {
  $scope.warranties = Warranty.query();
});
```

All other CRUD operations will be automatically added into your Warranty object.
For more information, you can visit [ngResource Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Answer (score 0):

The same way you communicate with any API, use the [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) service.

With this you get HTTP verb shorthands:

```
// Returns a promise with warranty list as a resolved parameter
function getWarranties() {
  return $get('/api/warranty').then(function(resp) {
    return resp.data;
  });
}
```

Or you can use the raw `$http` method:

```
// Returns a promise with warranty list as a resolved parameter
function getWarranties() {
  return $http({
    url: '/api/warranty',
    method: 'get',
    // other options...
  }).then(function(resp) {
      return resp.data;
  });
}
```